# How to run initialization code for a palette?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, initialization, mathematica-frontend

Occasionally it would be preferable to have some initialization code for palettes (of buttons).  For example, it could define some functions that are used by palette buttons.

**What is the easiest and preferable way to define/run initialization code for a palette?**

- The initialization can run either when the palette is loaded or when any button is pressed for the first time (*possible issue:* what if the kernel is restarted after the palette was loaded?)
- The definitions should be somehow localized (i.e. in their own context -- do unique notebook contexts help here?)
- If possible, I'd prefer a minimal effort solution (i.e. extra code at the fewest possible places, self contained palette file with no extra package files, palette creation using the existing convenience tools of palettes menu or `CreatePalette`, etc.)
- (You can assume that the initialization code runs fast, e.g. it consists of definitions only)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Despite some issues it might have (e.g. double or delayed initialization), it appears to have worked for the somewhat restricted use case I have.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard See here for a possible problem: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/n-lh8sc83Qs/discussion

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're right to be concerned about the visibility of the `Dynamic` being an issue.  The way to absolutely guarantee a `Dynamic` expression to be evaluated regardless of the visibility of any of the individual cells is to use `NotebookDynamicExpression`.  Here's an example that illustrates `NotebookDynamicExpression` working while a `Dynamic` fails because it's hidden within a closed cell group:

```
cell1 = First @ MakeBoxes[
    TextCell["Click to open", "Title", 
        CellMargins -> 0, System`WholeCellGroupOpener -> True],
    StandardForm];
cell2 = First @ MakeBoxes[
    ExpressionCell[DynamicWrapper["hidden cell", Print["DynamicWrapper"]]], 
    StandardForm];
CreatePalette[
    Notebook[{Cell[CellGroupData[{cell1, cell2}, Closed]]}, 
        NotebookDynamicExpression :>
            Dynamic[Refresh[Print["NotebookDynamicExpression"], None]]]]
```

When you evaluate this, note that the `Dynamic` in `NotebookDynamicExpression` evaluates immediately.  The `DynamicWrapper` never evaluates until you open the cell group, which you can do by clicking on the "Click to open" text.

In this example, incidentally, notice that I wrapped the `NotebookDynamicExpression` with `Refresh`.  The function `Refresh[#, None]&` will make sure that the code evaluates only once -- when the notebook is first opened.  Otherwise, the code would obey the standard properties of `Dynamic` and evaluate whenever any of the dependencies change.

`NotebookDynamicExpression` has been around since v6, but was only documented in v8.  Also documented are its related cousins, `CellDynamicExpression` and `FrontEndDynamicExpression`.

Comment: Welcome (back) to StackOverflow, and thank you for the asnwer!  It's good to finally see you here.  If you have time, perhaps you can also take a look at this front-end-related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353838/controlling-the-rasterize-width-for-notebook-related-expression

Comment: What will evaluate first, *DynamicExpression or visible dynamic? Or is this a rat race?

Answer (score 4):

A `DynamicBox` with `Initialization` is capable of the basic function.  You can size the palette such that the object is not visible, and it will still operate.

Here is code for a small sample palette.  It sets a value for `var`.  The active code is offset with whitespace.

```
(* Beginning of Notebook Content *)
Notebook[{
Cell[BoxData[{
 TagBox[GridBox[{
    {
     ButtonBox["\<\"TSV\"\>",
      Appearance->Automatic,
      ButtonFunction:>None,
      Evaluator->Automatic,
      Method->"Preemptive"]},
    {
     ButtonBox["\<\"CSV\"\>",
      Appearance->Automatic,
      ButtonFunction:>None,
      Evaluator->Automatic,
      Method->"Preemptive"]},
    {
     ButtonBox["\<\"Table\"\>",
      Appearance->Automatic,
      ButtonFunction:>None,
      Evaluator->Automatic,
      Method->"Preemptive"]}
   },
   GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Left}}},
   GridBoxItemSize->{"Columns" -> {{Automatic}}, "Rows" -> {{Automatic}}}],
  "Column"], "\[IndentingNewLine]", 

DynamicBox[Null,
   Initialization :> ($CellContext`var = "It is done, Master.")
]

}], NotebookDefault,
 CellMargins->{{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
 CellBracketOptions->{"Color"->RGBColor[0.269993, 0.308507, 0.6]},
 CellHorizontalScrolling->True,
 PageBreakAbove->True,
 PageBreakWithin->False,
 ShowAutoStyles->True,
 LineSpacing->{1.25, 0},
 AutoItalicWords->{},
 ScriptMinSize->9,
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 FontFamily:>CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"],
 FontSize:>CurrentValue["PanelFontSize"]]
},
WindowSize->{55, 105},
WindowMargins->{{Automatic, 583}, {Automatic, 292}},
WindowFrame->"Palette",
WindowElements->{},
WindowFrameElements->{"CloseBox", "MinimizeBox"},
StyleDefinitions->"Palette.nb"
]
(* End of Notebook Content *)
```

Comment: Hey, what palette is that? :D  My question is: are you sure that the initialization code will get executed *even if the `DynamicBox` is not visible*?  This doesn't seem to be the case here.  (But that is not a big issue, I think I can still use this approach.)

Comment: I made a notebook with a DynamicBox at the end (non-visible when opening the notebook).  After restarting Mathematica and re-opening the notebook, the initialization was not executed.  (It *was* executed later after I scrolled to the end.)  Just pointing this out.  Otherwise I can use the approach, and this is not an issue for me in practice.

Comment: @Szabolcs (#1) I am very fond of that palette. :-)  (#2) Strange, I checked that specifically, knowing that dynamic objects are inactive when hidden, and I found that it worked.  Perhaps because on my system, with the sample notebook, it is only *just* out of frame?