# Controlling the Rasterize[] width for notebook-related expressions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-frontend

**Update** Mr Wizard's answer gives pixel-perfect results, but it is Windows-only and destroys the clipboard contents.  My answer should work on any platform, but it's less precise: e.g. it omits In/Out labels.  It does allow setting the rasterization width though.

---

This problem came up when I was [trying to make a preview window for an image uploader](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8343460/695132) (see the end of that answer).

I would like to create a palette button that will upload the current notebook selection as an image.  Before uploading, I would like to show a preview of the image, to reduce the chance of something going awry before contacting the server.

This is what I have so far (includes only the preview code, not the uploader):

```
button = Button[
  "Preview",
  Module[
    {expr = NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]}, 
    If[expr =!= {},
      With[{img = Rasterize[expr]},
        MessageDialog[
          Column[{"Would you like to perform the action?", img}], 
          {"Do it!" :> doIt[img], "Cancel" :> Null}
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

<sup>In case you are wondering why I used a nested `With` inside the `Module` instead of making `img` a module-variable too: it's because by the time `doIt[img]` is evaluated, the local module variables will have been cleared, so I need to substitute the rasterized expression directly into the `doIt` function,</sup>

This button works (more or less).  You can try it by creating a graphic in the same notebook (e.g. `Graphics[Circle[]]`), selecting it using a single click, then clicking the Preview button.

However, if I put it in a palette using `CreatePalette[button]`, then the rasterization will happen for the window-width of the palette, and I get something like this:

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

**How can I control the width of rasterization, or more generally, how can I create a preview dialog for the uploader that avoids this issue?**

For an additional improvement, it would be nice to be able to size the message window so it fits the preview image (and still shows the button: the button disappears with `WindowSize -> All`).

---

### Answers

**Mr. Wizard's suggestion:**

```
button = Button[
  "Preview", (FrontEndExecute[
    FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], "CopySpecial", "MGF"]];
    MessageDialog[
    First@Cases[NotebookGet@ClipboardNotebook[], 
      RasterBox[data_, ___] :> 
       Image[data, "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Magnification -> 1], 
      Infinity]])]

CreatePalette[button]
```

**Problems:** It (probably) only works on Windows, and it destroys the clipboard contents.

Comment: I tried extracting the `WindowSize` from the `InputNotebook[]` and passing that through to the `ImageSize` or `RasterSize` options of `Rasterize`. But I couldn't find the magic construction (I don't think that `ImageSize->{{wmax},{hmax}}` works quite like it claims in the documentation). Have you tried something like this?

Comment: @Simon I tried, but didn't manage with `ImageSize`/`RasterSize`

Comment: Is the preview of major importance, or would getting the save itself working be a reasonable answer?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The whole point of the question is to get the preview.  To catch potential errors before [upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038288/upload-images-to-imgur-from-mathematica).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard You found a way to save it to a file?  BTW for my own personal use I think I'll be using your solution.  `Rasterize[]` doesn't always give me exactly what I see in the notebook (elements are shifted).

Comment: I thought I was making progress, but no, I did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this by copying the selection to a new notebook, rasterizing the full notebook, then closing it.

```
CreatePalette@Button["Preview",
  Module[{target},
   target = 
    CreateDocument[{}, WindowSelected -> False, Visible -> False];
   NotebookWrite[target, NotebookRead[SelectedNotebook[]]];
   CreateDialog[{Rasterize[target], DefaultButton[]}];
   NotebookClose[target]
   ]
  ]
```

The `WindowSize -> 500` option can be added to `CreateDocument` to set the rasterization width to 500 pixels.

---

Note some disadvantages (advantages in some cases) of this method compared to copying as bitmap:

- Custom styles are lost
- In/Out labels are lost
- Notebook magnification value is lost

If there's a need, some of these can be remedied by explicitly transferring some notebook options from the `SelectedNotebook` to the newly created one.

Answer (score 2):

If it is practical to use the clipboard in this operation you might use: `` FrontEnd`CopySpecial["MGF"] `` (copy as bitmap).

Comment: Let's have a more complete example, as it's not clear from your answer how this would work: ``CreatePalette@Button["Copy", 
 FrontEndExecute[
  FrontEndToken[FrontEnd`SelectedNotebook[], "CopySpecial", "MGF"]]]``  My aim is to get the current selection of a notebook previewed in a window (before uploading it as an image).  If I understand you right, you are suggesting using the clipboard for transferring the selection to the preview dialogue ...

Comment: ...  This has a couple of problems: 1. It will destroy the clipboard content even if I cancel the dialogue. 2. "MGF" only works on Windows according to the docs.  Otherwise it works quite fine.

Comment: @Szabolcs I wrote that right before bed, and I didn't work anything out.  I'll take another look at this whole problem today.  Also I forgot to +1 the question but I just corrected that.

Comment: Wow, what time zone are you in?

Comment: @Szabolcs, evidence indicates Martian.

Comment: That explains a few things :)

Comment: Although this is Windows-only, and destroys the clipboard even if I cancel the operation, it works great for personal use.  Now I have a single-button StackOverflow image uploader on a Mathematica palette :-)

Comment: @Szabolcs, Mac OS has a clipboard too doesn't it?  Why would your code break?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't *know* that it breaks, but [the docs say](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/frontendobject/CopySpecial.html) that "MGF" (i.e. copying in bitmap format) is Windows-only.

Comment: @Szabolcs that page (which I should have bothered to read before making baseless statements) seems to indicate that there is not a `Copy As (raster image format)` option on other systems.  Can that be true?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using ExportString[] to create the graphic into memory? (technically into a temp file, but what do you care:] )

```
ExportString[your_mathematica_stuff_here,"PNG",Background->None]
```

See the output on a colored background to verify transparent BG:

```
Framed[ImportString[ExportString[x^2,"PNG",Background->None]
                    ,"PNG"]
       ,Background->Yellow]
```

For images with many color variations (like 3D plots), I recommend JPEG2000 format, and for solid-colored images where transparency is not necessary, use GIF to preserve color detail.

Yes, you can control ImageSize when you export string of the image.

[image: ExportString output and image type/size comparison]

Comment: Have you tested this in a palette context?  Please replace `Rasterize` in my code by `ImportString@ExportString[..., "PNG]`, put the button on a palette, as I described, and you'll see that this is plagued by the same problem as plain `Rasterize`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work without you needing to make a new notebook:

```
button = Button["Preview", 
   Module[{expr = NotebookRead@InputNotebook[]}, 
    If[expr =!= {}, 
     With[{img = 
        Rasterize[expr, 
         ImageFormattingWidth -> 
          First@(WindowSize /. 
             AbsoluteOptions[InputNotebook[], WindowSize])]}, 
      MessageDialog[
       Column[{"Would you like to perform the action?", 
         img}], {"Do it!" :> doIt[img], "Cancel" :> Null},
       WindowSize -> {First@ImageDimensions@img, All}]]]]];
CreateDialog[button,
 WindowFloating -> True,
 WindowClickSelect -> False,
 Selectable -> False
 ]
```

I used a little option searcher to find `ImageFormattingWidth` and by passing the image width as the window width you can make the dialog fit the picture nicely and still display the button.

Here's a demo of its results:

[Rasterizing a cell from a pallete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eqeY.png)